# How can I access variable from a concatenated script that holds another script inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, nwjs

I have this code to open a file in NW.JS.

```
function chooseFile(name, handleFile) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        for(var f of this.files){
            console.log(f.name);
            console.log(f.path);
            handleFile(f.name, f.path);
        }
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
}
chooseFile('#fileDialog', function(name, path){ ... /* do something with the file(s) */ });
```

I have concatenated that code into a string so that I can inject it into a div (when that div is created) from a button click that generates the above code with unique id’s thusly..

```
var letsDoThis = '$(".' + imgUploadClass + '").click(function(){ var leid = this.id; var theEditId = "divId" + leid.slice(5); function ' + imgUploadChoose + '(name, handleFile) { var chooser = document.querySelector(name);chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) { for(var f of this.files){console.log(f.name);console.log(f.path);handleFile(f.name, f.path);}}, false);chooser.click();}' + imgUploadChoose + '("#' + imgUploadzz +'", function(name, path){' + 'alert(path);' + ';});});';
```

When testing I can access the name and path inside the alert box! GREAT! The code I want to run where

```
'alert("Hello!");’
```

is needs to be the following (but instead of a hardcoded url I need to access “path” from the (uniquely named) chooseFile script)...

```
'$("#" +' + 'theEditId).css("background-image", "url(http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg)");'
```

I am pretty sure I am not escaping a comma or something, here is another piece of code I got to fire correctly but not being able to access “path”...

```
'$("#" +' + 'theEditId).css("background-color", "green");'
```

Comment: What is this character `‘`? Have you tried using template literal?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo somehow. Corrected now. To clarify... that was not the problem, that was somehow a copy paste anomaly .

Comment: The whole idea of injecting JS as string is questionable. Why? Show your entire code please.